# how to upgrade laravel from 4.0 to 4.2 by keeping the old code base working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, upgrade

I am using laravel 4.0 for my website, and now i want to add few plugins to the website. But the plugin supports **laravel 4.2** , so  i want to upgrade to  laravel 4.2

I followed the official docs from laravel site but it dosen't work

My Composer.json is

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "navruzm/lmongo": "*",
    "imagine/imagine": "~0.5.0",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-develop",
    "thujohn/analytics": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Now when i try to update the composer i get errors like

```
symfony/security-core suggests installing symfony/validator (For using the user password constraint)
symfony/security-core suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using the expression voter)
phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing ext-gmp (Install the GMP (GNU Multiple Precision) extension in order to speed up arbitrary precision integer arithmetic operations.)
phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing pear-pear/PHP_Compat (Install PHP_Compat to get phpseclib working on PHP < 4.3.3.)
```

Comment: I suggest you go to IRC, in special to Freenode laravel channel

Comment: These arent errors but suggestions witch is totally different.Laravel got [Upgrading guide](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/upgrade) it might be a little bit frastuating process as you're upgrading from a very old version of laravel

Comment: The upgrade guide doesn't have a path for 4.0 - 4.2. Have you tried upgrading to 4.1 before upgrading to 4.2?

Comment: @CollinJames ya i tried to upgrade to 4.1,  still no help